# how to force method to be implemented in concrete subclass from trait

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I have a method in my trait

```
def controller: AnyRef
```

but my concrete class was not implementing that method and it was still compiling.  The compiler doesn't let me add abstract to that method either.  How can I create a method in a trait that forces it's implementer to implement it?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Is the class extending your trait abstract?

Comment: yes, and I figured it out.  in the concrete subclass, there was a val controller = new Controller and when that happens, for some reason, calling controller in the trait method ends up returning null.  I added the true answer below(but then have a new question as to why it compiles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler enforces that concrete classes implement all the abstracts methods they inherit from superclasses and traits.

If your class was compiling it meant it wasn't concrete, i.e. it was a `trait` or an `abstract class`, and you can't force neither to implement the abstract method.

Of course, as soon as you try to obtain a concrete instance the compiler will raise an error as the method is not implemented.

Practical example in the REPL

```
scala> trait A { def controller: AnyRef }
defined trait A

scala> trait B extends A
defined trait B

scala> abstract class C extends A
defined class C

scala> class D extends A
<console>:8: error: class D needs to be abstract, since method controller in trait A of type => AnyRef is not defined
       class D extends A

scala> new B { }
<console>:10: error: object creation impossible, since method controller in trait A of type => AnyRef is not defined
              new B { }
                  ^

scala> new C
<console>:10: error: class C is abstract; cannot be instantiated
              new C
```

Comment: ah, I could have sworn I had that compiling with abstract method and running and it returned null in my case but for some reason today I cannot reproduce it :(.

Comment: I can reproduce it now.  In the concrete subclass there was a val controller = new TheController() and in this case, the trait ends up returning null when you call controller in that case.  This seems like a scala bug or something.

Comment: it's probably an order of initialization issue. You should open a new question for that specific problem, with a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

If you are not getting any compilation error for such case, I think your IDE has some problem, try refresh/clean your project.

If your trait has implementation of "controller" function, then the concrete class(non abstract class) extending trait need **not** have any implementation for "controller" function. That's the **beauty of trait** in Scala, not forcing all the concrete class to implement some common methods with same implementation.

Comment: turns out if you have concrete subclass with val controller= new Controller, it compiles!!! and worse, it returns null instead of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

well, there seems to be some weird scala issue occuring.

When you have a concrete subclass that has a

```
val controller = new Controller
```

it seems to affect the traits controller and having your trait call controller results in null being returned.  Everything compiles just fine (though I think that might be a scala bug as I don't 'think' that should actually compile).

If it should compile, then can someone please explain why it compiles.